# Open document using WordprocessingDocument in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using  WordprocessingDocument to open a doc file.
But if file is not corrupted still it goes into catch part..
Here is the code:

```
bool savedSuccesfully = false;
if (System.IO.File.Exists(path[0])) //path[0] is doc file path
{
    try
    {
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path[0], true)) //FROM this line it goes to catch part
        {
            savedSuccesfully = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        savedSuccesfully = false;
    }
```

What is the issue?

Comment: What is the Exception you are getting?

Comment: @Manolete `File is corrupted`..

Comment: I've had instances where even though opening the file through explorer by double-clicking opens fine in Word, opening it by file->open tells me that the file is corrupted. Try it. IF is corrupted, then you have the arduous task of finding out how to fix it.

Comment: Doc file is correctly open by doing `file > open`..@Ric